# I want to extract a .tgz file and extract any subdirectories that have files that are .tgz and .tar

Tags: python, gzip, tar, compression

I'm using the code below to extract `.tgz` files. The type of log files (`.tgz`) that I need to extract have sub-directories that have other `.tgz` files and `.tar` files inside them. I want to extract those too.

Ultimately, I'm trying to search for certain strings in all `.log` files and `.txt` files that may appear in a `.tgz` file.

Below is the code that I'm using to extract the `.tgz` file. I've been trying to work out how to extract the sub-files (`.tgz` and `.tar`). So far, I've been unsuccessful.

```
import os, sys, tarfile

try:
    tar = tarfile.open(sys.argv[1] + '.tgz', 'r:gz')
    for item in tar:
        tar.extract(item)
    print 'Done.'
except:
    name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    print name[:name.rfind('.')], '<filename>'
```

Comment: This seems to be a great Use Case for a recursion. You provide the first tarfile to the function and if it encounters another tar-file, the function is calls itself with the new tar file. If you find a log-file, you can invoke another function that handles logfiles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

```
import os, sys, tarfile

def extract(tar_url, extract_path='.'):
    print tar_url
    tar = tarfile.open(tar_url, 'r')
    for item in tar:
        tar.extract(item, extract_path)
        if item.name.find(".tgz") != -1 or item.name.find(".tar") != -1:
            extract(item.name, "./" + item.name[:item.name.rfind('/')])
try:

    extract(sys.argv[1] + '.tgz')
    print 'Done.'
except:
    name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    print name[:name.rfind('.')], '<filename>'
```

As @cularis said this is called recursion.

Comment: The code unzips the .tgz file and dislays a folder - 'storage', and in that folder there are two other folders = 'Folder1' & 'Folder'2, both which have .tgz files and .tar files that have not been extracted. The above code is only unzipping the main .tgz file, but not files in subfolders.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the tar files. Code updated. Nevertheless it was unzippping .tgz in subfolders. Now it is working both for .tar and .tgz files nested in archive.

Comment: how would I execute this same code as a script instead of from the cmd line? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by saying to execute it as a script? How do you want to start it and how would you like the script to behave?